# Error with First() step in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

1. I'm read a file using following code:

   data=sc.textFile("fileToRead.csv")

When I'm doing

```
data.count()
```

it's giving me no error and I'm getting count of rows. But if I'm doing

```
data.first()
```

it's giving me the following error. I'm putting the entire error log here.

Can anyone please tell me where I'm doing mistake?

Thanks a lot!

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-9c10a21c6028> in <module>()
----> 1 first=train.first()

C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py in first(self)
   1313         ValueError: RDD is empty
   1314         """
-> 1315         rs = self.take(1)
   1316         if rs:
   1317             return rs[0]

C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\rdd.py in take(self, num)
   1295 
   1296             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1297             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1298 
   1299             items += res

C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\context.py in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
    937         # SparkContext#runJob.
    938         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
--> 939         port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
    940         return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
    941 

C:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    812         return_value = get_return_value(
--> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
    814 
    815         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     43     def deco(*a, **kw):
     44         try:
---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
     46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     47             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    309             else:
    310                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 14, localhost): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1765)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1765)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239
```

Comment: What happens if you call `data.take(1)`? Does it give the same error?

Comment: @Psidom: Thanks for your comment. I was getting the same error. It's seem to be system bottleneck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me like an executor is dying mysteriously, and the exception you include got thrown when some other executor tried to talk to it.  From your output: "Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error".

My experience in these situations is that an executor ran into a resource paucity, and was killed.  Typically a shortage of memory.

I see in the output you include the text: "Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times".  So "first" is being called in "Stage 8" --- I suspect that something that happened in one of the earlier stages bloated the memory footprint of a Spark executor.

I assume you are running on top of yarn?  Unfortunately when things go wrong down in the guts of yarn, Spark's error reporting in my experience has been poor.  If you really want to know exactly what went wrong, you have to dig into the yarn logs out on all the nodes.  On the other hand, Spark does a beautiful job of reporting the fatal exception if anything goes wrong in the python code you've written.

My impression is that you are just starting to experiment with Spark?  If so, I suspect you aren't tuning the amount of memory your executors and driver are allowed to use.  The defaults are almost always too low.  If you are running on EMR, there's a wonderful new "spark" configuration parameter in EMR-4.x, "maximizeResourceAllocation", that gives the executors an appropriately generous amount of memory.  You still have to tune the amount of the driver's memory, AFAIK.

One quick and dirty way to set the executor and driver memory is to do it on the command line:

```
spark-submit --executor-memory 10G --driver-memory 2G my_spark_app.py ...
```

The amount of memory you specify should be less than the physical memory of the nodes.  If you've got the nodes all to yourself, try using 70% of the memory; leave the rest as elbow room for the kernel and other things.

You'll also want to tune the number of cores your executors can use.  The default is typically way too low.  If running in in yarn-client mode, I set the number of executor cores to one less than the physical number of cores.  (I leave the extra one there to leave room for the "application manager" yarn container; I make the reasonable assumption that yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores is set to the number of physical cores.)

```
spark-submit --executor-cores 31 --executor-memory 10G --driver-memory 2G my_spark_app.py ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was actually the memory issue. When I reduces the file size, the error was gone. I was practicing spark on my PC. So not much scope of drastically increasing the memory and other issues. Thanks again!